# count the duplicate rows in pandas, and a very big csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tyring to count the duplciate rows in a csv file. An example look like the following

```
head tail count

134;  135;  1

134;  136;  1

134;  137;  2

134;  135;  2

134;  136;  1
```

and want the duplicate rows (on head and tail columns) to be count and add the count together.

result looks like the following

```
head tail count

134;  135;  3

134;  136;  2

134;  137;  2
```

Another problem is that the csv file is super big (60GB), RAM is 64G btw,  if set the chunksize to some number and do the iteration like:

```
for df in pd.read("*.csv", sep = ";",chunksize = 100000):

     do the duplicate count
```

the count process will only be done in that part of df and not globally.

So what we want is actually to do the count in the whole file, but the file is too big.

Thanks

hz

Comment: You just want the count and override df at each iteration?

Comment: Hi corralien, nope, I want the count in the big csv file

Comment: This is what my solution does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Counter` from `collections` module:

Input data:

```
>>> %cat data.csv
head;tail;count
134;135;1
134;136;1
134;137;2
134;135;2
134;136;1
```

```
from collections import Counter

for df in pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=';', chunksize=2):
    c.update(df.groupby(['head', 'tail'])['count'].sum().to_dict())
```

Output result:

```
>>> c
Counter({(134, 135): 3, (134, 136): 2, (134, 137): 2})
```

Convert the Counter to a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index', columns=['count'])
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['head', 'tail'])
df = df.set_index(mi).reset_index()
```

```
>>> df
   head  tail  count
0   134   135      3
1   134   136      2
2   134   137      2
```

Comment: @hz2021. Do you have enough time to check if my answer solves your problem?

Comment: Hi Corralien , I checked and it did work!

Comment: I'm wondering how to "accept" this answer, or do I need to do it?  Sorry I'm new to this community. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use DuckDB to perform the distinct count and then export the result to a pandas dataframe.

Duckdb is a vectorized state-of-the-art DBMS for analytics and can run queries directly on the CSV file. It is also tightly integrated with Pandas so you can easily import/export data to dataframes.

To install DuckDB you can simply run a
pip install duckdb

The following code should work for your purposes:

```py
import duckdb
rel = duckdb.from_csv_auto(temp_file_name)
count_query = ''' SELECT column0, COUNT(column0)
FROM my_name_for_rel
GROUP BY column0
HAVING COUNT(column0)>1'''
res = rel.query('my_name_for_rel', count_query)
data_frame = res.df()
```